# what is the InternetExplorer SSL\TLS Handshake WINDOWS API

Tags: internet-explorer, winapi, ssl

what api is being used in InternetExplorer to create an SSL Session.

specifically the Generation of the key \ mastersecret and the beginning of the session.

Answer (score 0):

There's really no simple answer to your question, which involves hundreds of thousands of lines of code.

Internet Explorer makes network calls using `WinINET`. WinINET establishes HTTPS connections using `SChannel` which also uses `CryptoAPI`.

You can learn more about how secure connections are made here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374782(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Well thats article is very informative
having a piece of code could be awesome, but im looking for just the right API calls (in the right order..?)
I'm just clueless about them
And which api call would give me the ClientHello (sniffing in wireshark)